# Pushing a Zend Application into Amazon EC2 Instance

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to push a zend application onto an amazon EC2 instance.

I have set up my Zend application on the server and have set up the httpd conf.

When I try to access my website through the browser, I get the following message printed:

```
bootstrap() ->run();
```

I have followed all the standard procedures and am able to see static HTML files. But when I try to access PHP files, I see a blank page.

I checked the log files but those do not return any errors.

Any idea why I'm facing this issue.

**Update:**

I updated my php.ini file with the zend library include_path.

Now I'm faced with the following error:

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Exception' with message 'Resource
matching "Jquery" not found' in /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/Application/Bootstrap
    /BootstrapAbstract.php:694 Stack trace: #0 /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/Application
    /Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(626): 
    Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_executeResource('Jquery') #1 /usr/share/php/libzend-
    framework-php/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(586): 
    Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_bootstrap(NULL) #2 /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-
    php/Zend/Application.php(355): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->bootstrap(NULL) #3 
    /var/www/html/urban-chatter/public/index.php(29): Zend_Application->bootstrap() #4 {main} thrown in 
    /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php on line 694
```

Comment: I now included the zend library in php.ini file but now it it throwing the following error:
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Exception' with message 'Resource matching "Jquery" not found' in /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php

Comment: You need update in your question directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:**

I copied the zend library from my system onto the server and changed the include_path to the new library in php.ini file and everything started working. I think there was some compatibility issues when I used another version of zend library.